# Out Of Memory Exception occuring in android even after recycling Bitmap

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, picasso

i have read many threads on this topic and tried to use them in my code but i am still not able to solve it.

**What i am trying to do:**
Like facebook or any other app which downloads feed from server which includes image, I am also doing same and trying to display feeds and images on the image view.

What is happening:
I am able to download the feeds (in JSON) which includes URL of images and i am able to show them on ImageView.
In Emulator my MAX heap size is 64MB. I am consuming around 30MB in first 10 feeds( not sure why but this is what i get from Memory tab in Android monitor of Android Studio and Even in Android Device monitor).
I have a refresh button in my app which reloads the same feeds after removing all feeds which were earlier populated. I expected that i will be consuming the same memory or some what more. But contrary to that my memory usage got increased upto 42MB. Hence after tapping on refresh for 3 to 4 times, it is causing OutOFMemory Execption. Even if i load next 10 feed or 50 feeds at a time i am getting OutOfMemory Exception.

I know that facebook instagram and many more such apps does the same thing but not sure how they implemented the code to cover this situation.

Below is my code for populating feed

```
private void loadFeed(List<Feed> feedList)
{
    Log.v(Constant.TAG,"Loading Feed in social feed page");
    for(final Feed feed:feedList) {
        LinearLayout feedBox = new LinearLayout(this);
        feedBox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        FrameLayout profileDetailContainer= new FrameLayout(this);
        LinearLayout profileDetailContainerParent=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout profileDetailContainerChild=new LinearLayout(this);
        profileDetailContainerChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ImageView imgProfile= new ImageView(this);
        TextView txtDate= new TextView(this);
        TextView txtName= new TextView(this);
        ImageView imgProduct= new ImageView(this);
        txtName.setText(feed.getUserFullName());
        TextView txtDesciption= new TextView(this);
        txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        if(feed.getDescription().length()>Constant.NUMBER_OF_DESCRIPTION_CHAR_SHOW_ON_RESULT)
        {
            txtDesciption.setText(feed.getDescription().substring(0,Constant.NUMBER_OF_DESCRIPTION_CHAR_SHOW_ON_RESULT)+"...");
        }
        else
            txtDesciption.setText(feed.getDescription());

        if(!IOUtil.fileExists(this,feed.getProductImageName())) {
            WebRequest request = new WebRequest();
            request.setUrl(Constant.ROOT_APPLICATION_URL_WITH_SEPARATOR + feed.getImgPath());
            request.setParam(feed.getId() + "");
            new ImageDownloadTask(this, true, feed.getProductImageName(), this).execute(request);
            Log.v(Constant.TAG,"URL:"+Constant.ROOT_APPLICATION_URL_WITH_SEPARATOR+feed.getImgPath());
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.logo).into(imgProduct);
            feedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ScreenUtility.alertException(v.getContext(),"Please wait untill product image loads");
                }
            });
            PixyfiSession.save(feed.getId() + "", imgProduct);
            PixyfiSession.save(feed.getId() + "_feed", feed);

        }
        else
        {
            ImageUtil.recycleIfPossible(imgProduct);
            try {
                imgProduct.setImageBitmap(ImageUtil.getLocalImage(feed.getProductImageName(),this));
                FeedboxOnClickListener feedboxOnClickListener = new FeedboxOnClickListener(feed);
                feedBox.setOnClickListener(feedboxOnClickListener);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.v(Constant.TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
            }

        }

        if(FacebookUtil.localProfilePicExists(feed.getUserName(),this))
        {
            Bitmap profileImage= FacebookUtil.getLocalProfilePicture(feed.getUserName(),this);
            imgProfile.setImageBitmap(profileImage);
        }
        else {
            FacebookUtil.loadProfilePicture(feed.getUserName(),this,this);
            PixyfiSession.save(feed.getUserName(),imgProfile);
            imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
        }
        try {

            if(feed.getDate()==null) {
                txtDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(feed.getFeedDate())));
            }
            else {
                txtDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(feed.getDate()));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(Constant.TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);
        layoutParam.setMargins(5,5,0,0);
        imgProfile.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);

        layoutParam= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
        layoutParam.setMargins(20,5,0,0);
        txtName.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
        layoutParam= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.LEFT);
        layoutParam.setMargins(20,5,0,0);
        txtDate.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);

        profileDetailContainerParent.addView(imgProfile);
        profileDetailContainerChild.addView(txtName);
        profileDetailContainerChild.addView(txtDate);
        profileDetailContainerParent.addView(profileDetailContainerChild);
        feedBox.addView(profileDetailContainerParent);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams feedLayoutParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        feedLayoutParam.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        imgProduct.setLayoutParams(feedLayoutParam);
        txtDesciption.setLayoutParams(feedLayoutParam);
        feedBox.addView(txtDesciption);
        feedBox.addView(imgProduct);
        feedLayoutParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        feedLayoutParam.setMargins(0,5,0,5);
        feedBox.setLayoutParams(feedLayoutParam);

        feedBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
        PixyfiSession.save(feed.getId()+"_feedbox",feedBox);
        imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PixyfiSession.save(Constant.SELECTED_USER_ID,feed.getUserName());
                ScreenUtility.loadScreen(v.getContext(),UsersProfile.class,false);
            }
        });
        this.feedContainer.addView(feedBox);

    }
    if(feedList.size()==Constant.FEED_SIZE_IN_ONE_REQUEST)
    {
        Button moreFeed= new Button(this);
        moreFeed.setText("Load MOre Feed");
        moreFeed.setOnClickListener(new MoreFeedButtonListener(this));
        this.feedContainer.addView(moreFeed);
    }
    this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

For reloading/refreshing the feed

```
this.currentPage=1;
this.recycleImages();
this.feedContainer.removeAllViews();
PixyfiSession.save(Constant.CURRENT_FEED_PAGE,this.currentPage);
this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
loadFeed();
```

recycleImages Method:

```
private void recycleImages()
{
    for(int i=0;i<this.feedContainer.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        if(this.feedContainer.getChildAt(i) instanceof  ImageView)
        {
            ImageView view=(ImageView)this.feedContainer.getChildAt(i);
            ImageUtil.recycleIfPossible(view);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need further details on the code then please let me know.
Also is it possible to see memory usage of other apps like facebook in android device monitor?
**UPDATE**
ImageUtil.getLocalImage Method

```
public static Bitmap getLocalImage(String imageName, Context context) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    if(IOUtil.fileExists(context,imageName)) {
        is = context.openFileInput(imageName);
        bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Image file doesn't exists");
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: You should inflate the layout as there are too many ui components .it will reduce the chances of view leakage. And also if you can use recycler view than it will be much helpful.

Comment: I don't follow you. I am adding views dynamically, if that is what you mean by inflating layout. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: By inflating the layout mean ,you should define your layout in xml file and than use this. It will be easy to manage,and recyclerview will help you to reuse same view again , ultimately less number of view will be used during feed load

Comment: Actually the number of views is unknown to me. I receive 10 feeds at a time and user may load next 10 feed which i need to display in same activity/screen. Hence i am dynamically creating 10 more layouts/view to add to my linearlayout. And when user repopulate feeds then i remove all views from my feedcontainer which is linearlayout and start adding new feeds.

Comment: I cant add xml from very beginning. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you don't want to use xml,still you should at least try recycler view it will best memory optimized way to display a list data ,it will also force viewholder pattern .

Comment: You mean i should reiterate my linearlayout and recycle all views like i did for bitmaps in recycleImages method? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: No i mean recyclerview , alternative to list view check thi link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: I am not using ListView i am using linearlayout

Comment: Replaced Linearlayout with listview did the trick.

Comment: Cool ,so may i put this as answer ,it will keep us motivated, and also help other.

Comment: You mean you wanna post answer? Sure u can

Comment: You should accept my answer ,if it works for you, it will do the trick for other too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding the answer :

Instead of managing the view components yourself you should always prefer listview or better recycler view.
Because it help you avoid view leaks and provide better reuse of views that you already created.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem add this line to your manifest in application tag:

```
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to solve the problem, just delay it. You need to use the appropriate widget or view type, like the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As [Saber Safavi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955782/4304769) told do that first and then add

```
 defaultConfig {
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
    ....
}
```

in your

> app/build.gradle

file..

Comment: Multidex allows me to write more than 65536 methods. I do not have have problem is referring to my methods. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have problem with loading images. Please check your `ImageUtils.getLocalImages`, did you decode and load a scaled version of images into memory, or did you load original images into memory?

Follow [this document from Android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) , i think it's the best tutorial for loading images efficiently in Android.

Comment: tried sampling the image and as result i found that my emulator has width of 1080 pixel (i am using full width for imageview) where as image i am loading has max of 1024pixel. So that also won't work.

Comment: Could you show me the implementation of this method `ImageUtils.getLocalImages` ?

Answer (score 0):

Image handling in Android is very very tricky. Better use a library which has been built to take care of the situation and complexities involved.
I prefer 
UniversalImageLoader or Piccaso!

Comment: I am using Picasso for same reason. Its there in above code as well. Do you see any problem with the way i am using Picasso?

Comment: Hi Kumar, why are you using a method called getLocalImage? From my understanding, Picasso takes care of handling disk images. If not please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Ruchira: i guess you took me wrong. Actually i am pretty new with android that is why i asked you to correct me.

Comment: Well i feel like that might be the mistake i am doing. I will try and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Okay Kumar! Good luck!

Comment: tried. It is consuming lesser memory but ultimately throws OOM as feed increases

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are keeping too many bitmap images in Run-time memory, try not to create too many images and try nullifying them.

Mobile devices typically have constrained system resources. Android devices can have as little as 16MB of memory available to a single application. Virtual Machine Compatibility gives the required minimum application memory for various screen sizes and densities. Applications should be optimized to perform under this minimum memory limit. However, keep in mind many devices are configured with higher limits.

I will not recommend you for the heapSize flag in android manifest. I hope you are not developing games :), Rather go for retrofit or any other image processing library if you want. I would suggest you to look at BitmapFun sample provided by Google. It is available on developer portal.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Cheers!!